# In AVD I get Unfortunately, PruebaNumero3 has stopped working

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm already look for an answer in other questions, but i didn't found it or didn't see it, i'm grateful for any help thanks.

**these are the errors shown in the Log Cat**

```
E/Trace(1417): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

 E/AndroidRuntime(1417): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{gabrielrojas.com/gabrielrojas.com.primeraventana}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class textview

 E/AndroidRuntime(1417): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class textview
```

**The androidmanifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
android:name=".PruebaNumero3"
android:label="@string/title_activity_prueba_numero3" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".primeraventana"/>
<activity android:name=".segundaventana" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

**PruebaNumero3.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:text="@string/hello_world"
tools:context=".PruebaNumero3" />
<Button android:id="@+id/boton1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/Primera_Ventana"/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/boton2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
android:text="@string/Segunda_Ventana" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**PruebaNumero3.java**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_prueba_numero3);
// Visualizamos Los botones
Button boton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton1);
Button boton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton2);

// Fijamos los eventos que haran ir a las otras actividades

boton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent intent = new Intent(PruebaNumero3.this, primeraventana.class);
startActivity(intent);
}} );

boton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent intent = new Intent(PruebaNumero3.this, segundaventana.class);
startActivity(intent); 
}} );} 



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_prueba_numero3, menu);
return true;
} } ;
```

**primeraventana.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<textview android:id="@+id/textview1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/Escala_Uno"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/boton3"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/Menú_Principal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**primeraventana.java**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.primeraventana);


TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
Button boton3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton3);

text.setText(R.string.Escala_Uno);

boton3.setText(R.string.MenÃº_Principal);


boton3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
finish();
```

**segundaventana.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<textview android:id="@+id/textview2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/Escala_Dos"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/boton4"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/Menú_Principal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**segundaventana.java**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.primeraventana);


TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview2);
Button boton4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton4);

text.setText(R.string.Escala_Dos);
boton4.setText(R.string.MenÃº_Principal);


boton4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
finish ();
```

Comment: In primeraventana.xml and segundaventana.xml, shouldn't the "T" and "V" in `textview` be capital?

Comment: Atleast study the code before copy pasting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `primeraventana.xml` layout file. You opened `TextView` tag with textview which is not existing. Change it as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView android:id="@+id/textview1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/Escala_Uno"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/boton3"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/Menú_Principal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot!, it was a silly mistake, the code had another error in segundaventana.java on setContentView i had"primeraventana", im just strating to work with java and eclipse, once again thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what the problem is, but I do have a few things you can try:

1)
In primeraventana.xml your TextView should be spelled in capitals. Like so:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Escala_Uno"/>
```

2)
In segundaventana.java the String names can only be English letters and numbers. Remove the "Ãº" in:

```
boton4.setText(R.string.MenÃº_Principal);
```

Lastly, I declare OnClickListeners() like this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickLister() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // You code here.
    }
}
```

I don't know weather that makes any difference to not having the View. It just looks nicer. :)